# Way to "rip" bicycle directions from Google Maps Classic?

Tags: google-maps

It's very unfortunate that Google Maps Classic no longer exports routes as a KML file, and Google Maps Engine Lite isn't as easy to use.

So I was wondering if it were possible to somehow "rip" [a route drawn in Google Maps Classic](http://goo.gl/maps/Wx7Cg), possibly through some local JavaScript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the method described on [this blog post](http://bedsforcyclists.co.uk/articles/2014/04/13/how-to-plan-a-route-in-google-maps-and-export-it-to-gpx-your-phone/) still works:

> ### Plan Your Route
>
> Head over to Google Maps, select the cycle option and start planning a
> route.
>
> Once you are happy with the route, copy the page’s URL link in the
> address bar to your clipboard.
>
> ### Convert to gpx
>
> Open up a new tab and goto http://www.gpsvisualizer.com/convert_input
>
> You can ignore most the options, just select Gpx and  paste the Google
> Maps URL into the box labelled “provide the URL of a file on the Web”
> and then press the Convert button

Instead of GPX, just use the [KML option](http://www.gpsvisualizer.com/map_input?form=googleearth).

Comment: If you're interested in Route-points rather than fixed Track-Points then you can use this utility instead: http://labs.coruscantconsulting.co.uk/garmin/gpxgmap/convert.php

Answer (score 3):

The new Google Maps allows you to export as KML directly via My Maps, and appears to have been vastly improved since Maps Engine Lite first showed up.

1. Click the Menu button
2. Click 'My Maps'
3. Click 'Create'
4. Click the Draw a Line button then 'Add biking route' and start tracing your route*
5. Click the three dots button to the right of the 'Add Layer' and 'Share' buttons, then 'Export to KML'
6. Select the relevant map layer, choose between KML and KMZ**, and click 'Download'

* Note that you can only add 25 points along an A-B route, and you can only have 12 A-B routes per layer.

** If you export as KML it's easy to edit these files in Notepad++ or similar and join multiple A-B routes together for longer journeys. You can then re-import your edited KML into My Maps, Google Earth, or a GIS.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this is not considered too off topic, but [CycleStreets](http://www.cyclestreets.net/) does much better cycle routes by using the rich OSM metadata on roads and smaller, often pedestrian-only paths. You can export both KML and GPX.

They also have an [API](http://www.cyclestreets.net/api/) if you want to do stuff programmatically.